# Run a command before reboot (Ubuntu)

Tags: 12.04, umount

I would like to run this command when Ubuntu reboots (before reboot/shutdown):

```
sudo umount /home/dataserver
```

How would I do this?

Comment: It would probably be best to ask this on Super User or on Ask Ubuntu. Also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48973/execute-a-command-before-shutdown looks like it's your best bet.

Comment: I've made script in both rc0.d and rc6.d but its not executing on reboot... 
As For startup I can use /etc/rc.local - is there something similar for shutdown ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### alternative one

Did you remember to give the `rc0.d/K99myscript` correct prefix? `K99` and 
`sudo chmod +x K99myscript`?

Note: The scripts in the directory are executed in alphabetical order. [Runlevel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel) 0 corresponds to shutdown, and 6 to reboot.

- `rc0.d/` is for shutdown or Halt.
- `rc6.d/` is for restart.

Quick and dirty explanation of system V:

The `rcX.d` is the **System V**'s init scripts links. The scripts are all symbolic links whose targets are located in `/etc/init.d/` The links are updated with [update-rc.d](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/update-rc.d.8.html).

The `K` stands for Kill, it just indicates that the linked script is stopping a service. On the other hand you can also use `S`, that is shorthand for Start, to indicate that you are running a single command or starting a service.

The [SK]NNmyscript number indicates in which order the linked scripts in the `rcX.d` are executed.

### alternative two

`/etc/init/yourscript.conf`

```
# This task do ---
# on shutdown.

description     "runs my script eg."

start on runlevel [06]

task

script
    exec *command*
end script
```

For more info on alternative two check out [this cookbook eg](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#methods).

Comment: Thanks, K99 prefix works and when i placed it in rc6. Please tell the logic behind it...